# RSpec with FactoryGirl without Rails – where does it to look for models?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec

I am writing ActiveRecord Ruby application not using Rails. I would like to test models with FactoryGirl but I am struggling with configuration. Given the uninitialized constant error I guess it can't find models in `lib/models` folder.

I would like to know what folder structure rspec/FactoryGirl expect or how do I inform it about models’ location.

rspec -fd spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
…/spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./bin/rspec:17:in `load'
    from ./bin/rspec:17:in `<main>'
```

---

spec/models/user.rb

```ruby
describe User, type: :model do
  it 'can be instantiated' do
    user = User.new
    expect(user).to be_a User
  end
end
```

lib/models/user.rb

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I have created RSpec configuration with `rspec --init`:

.rspec

```
--color
--require spec_helper
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```ruby
require 'factory_girl'
require_relative 'support/factory_girl'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

end
```

spec/support/factory_girl.rb

```ruby
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryGirl.find_definitions
  end
end
```

spec/factories.rb

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username "johnny"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you are missing is that Rails loads all of the models before FactoryGirl from `spec_helper.rb` when running RSpec test suites.

Try loading all of your models at the top of your `spec_helper.rb`

```
root = File.expand_path('../', File.dirname(__FILE__))
Dir[File.join(root,'lib/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

require 'factory_girl'
require_relative 'support/factory_girl'

...
```

Comment: Thanks, this help me. While second line complained about missing `join` method for `String`, this modification seems to work: `Dir[File.join(root,'lib/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }` Now I’m hitting another issue as one of model contains `closure_tree` which leads to `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with id primary found.`

Comment: I updated the code to fix the join method error. The other error is a separate issue. Difficult to guess on that but does your `users` table include a primary key `id`?